Update Jar file using Maven's pom.xml/Maven - Replace a file/Directories in already created Jar
I have the jar xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT.jar in path: /home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/xyz-restservices/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
and in the path /home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/xyz-restservices/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
Both of those jar files having /com/xyzz/boot/data/
Now I want to update the jar such that it
takes all sub-folders/files from /home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/customer/ap/customer-a/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/customer-a-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT.jar``s  /com/xyzz/boot/data/` folder and replace them into

/home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/xyz-restservices/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
/home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/xyz-restservices/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT.jar
it should overwrite if file is already there for above 2 locations else it should add in the same jar,
now to achive above changes via maven in pom.xml i added below plugins :

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack-data-folder</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.xyzz.customer.ap</groupId>
                        <artifactId>customer-a</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${customer.dir}/data</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>com/xyzz/boot/data/**</includes>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>update-classes-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- Run during package phase -->
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${customer.dir}/data</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>```

unpack-data-folder is working,whaterver is there under data folder is being extracted at ${customer.dir}/data
but update-classes-jar is not working 
/home/r/.m2/repository/com/xyzz/xyz-restservices/1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT/xyz-restservices-1.1.0-1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
not updated with data extracted from ${customer.dir}/data

So what will be the way to update already created jar files via pom?
Reason is customer-a is customer specific and inside that there will be customer specific hibernate entities and we want to deploy customer 
specific hibernate entities(java classes)

